# Проверка типа объекта и вывод соответствующего сообщения

Tags: python

Как реализовать проверку типа объекта и чтобы по результату выводилось соответствующее сообщение. Сказали через словарь сделать, добавить сначала все типы в словарь.

Нужно получить такой результат:

```
Пример 2:
Введите данные: {‘a’: 10, ‘b’: 20}
Тип данных: dict (словарь)
Изменяемый (mutable)
Id объекта: 1705205308536
```

Пробую так:

```
object_enterin = {'a': 10, 'b': 20}  # Здесь вводится любой объект
data_types = {
    int: 'целые числа',
    float: 'вещественные числа',
    str: 'строка',
    tuple: 'кортеж',
    bool: 'логический',
    list: 'список',
    dict: 'словарь',
    set: 'множество'
}

for i_type in data_types.keys():
    ...
```

Comment: почему код в вопросе в виде фото, а не текстом?

Comment: включайте код текстом согласно правилам сайта. И в чем ваш вопрос?

Comment: ну пробуешь, и каков результат?

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что: 1) код включен не по правилам сайта; 2) цель размещения текста не объяснена; 3) само задание либо не понято автором, либо плохо поставлено (так как без всяких списков `print (type(x)`) и ценности для базы знаний не несет.

Comment: @Сергей ну может надо не <class 'int'> вывести, а на русском языке :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Лучше делайте проверку через функцию **isinstance(object, classinfo)**:

```
sample = 1
if isinstance(int, sample ):
    print(sample, '- тип int')
```

2. Ваш **data_types** - это не список, а словарь

Дополнение:

Если же все таки хотите в список вносить все типы и потом выводить название типа в зависимости от значения из списка то как вариант так:

```
list_data = [1, '2', 3.2]
lst_type = [int, float, str]
for element_data in list_data:
    for element_type in lst_type:
        if type(element_data) == element_type:
            print(f'Элемент: {element_data} имеет тип: {element_type.__name__}')
            continue
```

Выдаст:

```
Элемент: 1 имеет тип: int
Элемент: 2 имеет тип: str
Элемент: 3.2 имеет тип: float
```

И для сравнения аналогичный код, только с использованием ф-ции **isinstance()**:

```
list_data = [1, '2', 3.2]
lst_type = [int, float, str]
for element_data in list_data:
    for element_type in lst_type:
        if isinstance(element_data, element_type):
            print(f'Элемент: {element_data} имеет тип: {element_type.__name__}')
            continue
```

Как по мне - последний вариант на много лучше...

Comment: просьба дать пояснения, чем это объективно лучше?

Comment: @Сергей, ну во-первых - меньше кода, а во-вторых это лучше =)

Comment: и на каждый тип делать отдельную проверку? Где же меньше кода-то.

Comment: @Эникейщик, я просто показал как работать с функцией. У него в вопросе стоит сделать проверку типа. Данная функция делает проверку принадлежности к классу. Что не так?

Comment: Не так то, что этот ответ оторван от вопроса. В вопросе я вижу восемь типов. Нужно для каждого типа отдельно написать проверку? Восемь проверок. Это совсем не меньше кода, как вы тут утверждаете. Если бы вы дали пример использования функции с приведенным словарем, то был бы хороший ответ. А так он просто ни о чем.

Comment: @Эникейщик, мои 25 символов более читаемы, чем его 31 символ.

Comment: + У него вопрос написан делать проверку типа, это предполагает, что надо что-то сделать в каждом случае. В противном случае я вообще не вижу смысла делать проверку типа, когда все и так можно получить через **type()**

Comment: @Эникейщик, внес дополнение касаемо идеи его вопроса. Так устроит?

Comment: еще раз, ваши 25 символов проверяют ОДИН ЕДИНСТВЕННЫЙ тип. На 8 типов будет 200 символов. Что нужно сделать в каждой случае написано в вопросе.

Comment: В итоге ваше дополнение еще меньше читаемо, чем версия автора.

Comment: @Эникейщик, ну покажите свой вариант. Я лишь показал как сделать так, как он хочет - ЧЕРЕЗ СПИСОК!

Answer (score 0):

Просто получаем из словаря элемент по ключу, равному типу объекта. `if` проверяет, что такой элемент действительно есть в словаре, если его нет, то `get` вернёт `None`:

```py
i_type = data_types.get(type(object_enterin))
if i_type:
    print(i_type)
```

Вывод:

```
словарь
```

Comment: Только тут будет одно **НО**. Откуда взялся словарь? В вопросе написано, что надо через список =))

Comment: @АлексейБелкин Хм, да... Но ведь через список не оптимально же ))

Comment: cогласен. Эта задача вообще странная, но походу у преподавателя, который придумывал такое задание, свои тараканы в голове =)))